# Minhag Tradition of Ashkenaz

Tags: minhag, product-recommendation, ashkenazi

Looking for a book that discusses minhag Ashkenaz in detail with sources.  I am  specifically interested in minhagim that were practiced in the Oberland of Europe.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

שרשי מנהג אשכנז by R' Rav Binyomin Shlomo Hamburger (4 vols) is a popular set on the 'Yekkishe' Minhag.
While it is out of print, some stores still sell it, and a new edition is being prepared. Find out more and see sample pages at their [website](http://www.moreshesashkenaz.org/en/shorshei/7-shorshei).

Comment: Some books should come with a warning that they promote xenophobia. This is definitely one of them.

Comment: From what I've perused, I've come across nothing of the sort!!

Comment: @5303 Look at his entry on brich shmei.

Comment: It is available in English Translation http://www.amazon.com/Shorshei-Minhag-Ashkenaz-Ashkenaz-Sources/dp/1583303294